# How would you model the following in a database

Tags: sql-server

How would you model the following in a database (object types underlined)?

> a. A **student** can attend multiple classes.
>
> b. Each **class** is
>   associated with one school
>
> c. A **school** can have many classes
>
> d. Each class has one teacher
>
> e. A **teacher** can teach many classes

Comment: what have you tried? Show some effort then we can help you normalize or redesign

Comment: Interview question? - or is it homework?

Comment: Please ask a concrete question.. and as pointed earlier show us what you have tried and then ppl can suggest correction

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of what type of data-set I used to contain these objects I would have:

A list of **schools**, each of which contains it's **class** objects, each of which contains a *reference* to its **teacher** and **students**.

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to StackOverflow. As a new user you need to read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) to know the kind of questions you should ask. Most times it is required you show some effort on your part and why you are having problem progressing.

Here is a guide to your question

```
School(schoolID, name, ....)

--to associate with school add schoolID
Student(studentID, name, ...)

--to associate with school add schoolID
Teacher(teacherID, name, ....)

--associated with one school and one teacher as Foreign key
Class(classID, name,...., classTeacherID, schoolID) -- class belong to a Teacher and to a School

-- combination of studentID and classID must be unique
Student_AttendingClass(studentID, classID) -- Classes attended by student

Student   Class
-------------------
James     Class-A
James     Class-B
James     Class-C
Mike      Class-A
Mike      Class-C

--James attends 3 Classes: Class-A, Class-B and Class-C**


-- combination of teacherID and classID must be unique
Teacher_Class(teacherID, classID) --Classes taught by teacher

Teacher      Class
-------------------
Mr. Paul     Class-B
Mr. Paul     Class-C
Mr. Peter    Class-B
Mrs. Pat     Class-A
Mrs. Pat     Class-C

--Mr. Paul teaches Class-B and Class-C while Mr. Peter teaches only Class-B
```

Read more on Entity Relationship. Here is one: [Guide to table relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: No need for Teacher_Class, a class has one teacher.

Comment: that's the `e.` part - "a teacher can teach many classes"

Comment: That's a one to many relationship. Class has a reference of `classTeacherID`. You don't need a junction table for a one to many relationship.

Comment: In fact you've broken `d.` in your example. `Class B` is taught by `Mr Paul` and `Mr Peter`

Comment: @Chris Diver There is a difference between the two scenario. It's a real-life scenario. (d.) says a class can have one teacher. If I get the OP right, this is the teacher that Manages the class, not Teaches and there can only be one. (e.) There can be many that teach the class, including/excluding the class teacher e.g. Physics teacher is different from Chemistry Teacher and so on

Comment: It's not a real-life scenario, it's a scenario bound by the rules given. `d.` does not say a class *can* have one teacher it says `d. Each class *has* one teacher`. `e.` does not say that there can be many that teach a class, it says that `e. A teacher can teach many classes` not the other way around. A teacher can teach many classes, a class has one teacher. A one-many relationship `Teacher(TeacherId)` `Class(ClassId, TeacherId)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. next time onwards i'll show my efforts

Comment: Chris is right. we no need for Teacher_Class, because a class has one teacher. in part e. part - "a teacher can teach many classes" but 2 or more teachers cant teach same class.